# How to bitset the Book Type when burning a DVD on a SuperDrive?

Tags: dvd-burning

Does anyone know how to set the [Book Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_type) when burning a DVD (DVD+R DL in my case) in OS X? I'm making a backup copy of my car's navigation DVD, and it will only work right if I set the booktype to **DVD-ROM**.

I'm using a mid-2010 MacBook Pro, with a "MATSHITA DVD-R UJ-898" SuperDrive, and I've confirmed that it supports the Verbatim DVD+R DL medium I'm planning to use.